# How to set default source of a package that exists in multiple sources on gnome-software?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, snap, deb, flatpak

I use ubuntu 20.10 with gnome software, the deb version with snap and flatpak plugins and there are some applications that are available from different sources like the official repo, snap or/and flatpak. By default the snap version has the highest priority and is selected.

How can I choose the default source just like kde's discover?

For instance if "gedit" is available in snap and deb repo, how can I set the deb version to be the default?

Kde's discover lets you set the default source permanently.

[image]